# Is it possible to create anonymous objects from abstract classes / interfaces in VB.NET?

Tags: .net, vb.net

Is it also possible to create anonymous objects of interfaces and abstract classes?

For example, in Scala, I can do:

```
trait Something {

  val someProperty: Int
}

val mySomething = new Something() {

  override val someProperty: Int = 42
}
```

Is this possible in VB.net, too, and if yes, how do I do this?

Searching this issue did not yield any usable results, or I just did not hit the correct keywords. The only results I got were about anonymous types like [this documentation page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb385125.aspx) and [this tutorial](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb531244.aspx) on MSDN. However this does not seem to work as expected when I do something like:

```
Public MustInherit Class Something

    Public MustOverride ReadOnly Property SomeProperty as Integer
End Class
```

and where I want to use it:

```
Dim mySomething As New Something
With mySomething
    ' I expect to provide an implementation for the property here
End With
```

The compiler complains that `'New' cannot be used on a class that is declared 'MustInherit'`.

Is such an approach not possible in VB.net or do I do something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, in VB if you want a class that implements an interface or inherits from a particular base class, it's up to you to actually define such a class.

You've found the closest feature already - anonymous types - but you don't get to choose their base type nor have them implement any interfaces.

Comment: So I have to go with writing mock implementations for myself. I wanted to use these anonymous objects in a test...

Comment: If you're wanting mocks for testing, there are plenty of libraries already written for .NET that support doing that - but as I say, they're libraries, not language features.

Comment: OK, I will have a look at that.